# Tracking a java program

Tags: java, debugging, traceback

I've currently got a snippet of java code running in eclipse, which has a bug somewhere. In fixing the bug, I'd like to see what the program's actually doing. I know Java traces where the program goes when it displays an error message; can I access that data to find out where I'm going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes check the variable on debug mode keep the mouse on the variable and it should display its value. You also have a variables window where you can see all current variable with their values.

Comment: If you post the Exception you receive, we can explain it to you. If you know something's going wrong, you're going to need to post the code or do breakpoints

Comment: It's time to learn debugging.

Comment: If you are not familiar with breakpoints and debugging process this tutorial will help you http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html Breakpoints will help you to understand the flow of program and can see where it starts and stops. This way you will know where this error is coming from and what could be the solution.

Comment: @Lokesh mebbeh turn this into an answer?

Comment: Yes, I just turned this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not familiar with breakpoints and debugging process [this tutorial from Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) will help you. Breakpoints will help you to understand the flow of program and can see where it starts and stops.In debugging mode when you hover over variable you can actually see what's happening there and values as well. This way you will know where this error is coming from and what could be the solution.

Comment: +1. The Debug perspective of Eclipse also includes entire views to help you with that, like tables of variable values of the current scope, the possibility to watch certain values, inspect snippets non-linearly etcpp.